can not import dependency of GmSSL
feel doubted that I can't import dependency of GmSSL while its official website provides its coordinate
this is its official website https://github.com/GmSSL/GmSSL-Java
I would much appreciate your help
enter image description here
I was thinking if it was because something is wrong with my configuration of mvn in idea
